# Views No Results: Show Block Instead?

Tags: 7, blocks, views

I have a view that is set up to report breaking news from a "breaking news" text field. But this field is often empty, and in the no results behaviour, we would like to show one of our special offer blocks instead.

I can see an option for "Entity:Rendered Entity" in no results behaviour, but this is only nodes or users, I cant see a way to display a pre existing block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a module that exposes blocks to the view header/footer and no results. It's called the [Views Block Area](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_block_area).

> This module exposes all available blocks as a views area. This way you
>   can add any block inside a footer or header from your view.
>
> Blocks that are generated by views, can't be selected. These blocks
>   can be inserted by views areas.

This is also only for Drupal 7

Comment: Ah! Perfect! Just what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for Drupal 7...

The quick and dirty way would be to use a `Global: Text area`.  With the PHP text filter enabled, you can input the PHP code necessary to render your block.

```
$block = block_load( $module, $delta);  // if you defined the block via UI, then go to the configuration page for the block.  The configure URL follows the structure: block/manage/MODULE/DELTA/configure
$output = drupal_render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block))));
print $output;
```

See [block_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/block_load/7) and [_block_get_renderable_array()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/_block_get_renderable_array/7).
The PHP Filter is explained here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1046700

Here's a really long conversation of people struggling to just try to render a block by hand: https://www.drupal.org/node/1034524

Optimally I'd be able to point you to a module, but I can't find one.

Comment: I would avoid PHP Filter if at all possible.

Comment: I agree.  Good module find.